# Flutter crashes in emulator when flutter app reopens from screen containing GoogleMap Widget

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, android-emulator

I used the GoogleMaps widget in my app and noticed that it crashed whenever i minimised the app and reopened it. So i did a verbose run in terminal and got the following log just before the app exited.

> flutter run -v

```
[        ] W/le.great_place(16700): Accessing hidden method
Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
[+18210 ms] W/le.great_place(16700): Accessing hidden method
Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,
linking, allowed)
[        ] W/le.great_place(16700): Accessing hidden method
Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist,
linking, allowed)
[        ] W/le.great_place(16700): Accessing hidden method
Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
[+2733 ms] D/EGL_emulation(16700): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdefcff80: ver 1 0 (tinfo
0xbf735300)
[  +30 ms] D/EGL_emulation(16700): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd39cd5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo
0xd3a25b50)
[        ] E/flutter (16700): [ERROR:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl.cc(72)]
Failed to setup Skia Gr context.
[  +19 ms] D/EGL_emulation(16700): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf07cf40: ver 3 0 (tinfo
0xd3a25980)
[  +60 ms] F/libc    (16700): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR),
fault addr 0x8 in tid 16728 (1.raster), pid 16700 (le.great_places)
[  +83 ms] *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
[        ] Build fingerprint:
'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QSR1.190920.001/5891938:user/release-keys'
[        ] Revision: '0'
[        ] ABI: 'x86'
[        ] Timestamp: 2020-11-16 22:39:13+0300
[        ] pid: 16700, tid: 16728, name: 1.raster  >>> com.example.great_places
<<<
[        ] uid: 10135
[        ] signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
[        ] Cause: null pointer dereference
[        ]     eax 00000000  ebx bee86920  ecx fffffff9  edx 00000000
[        ]     edi 00000004  esi 00000000
[        ]     ebp bce01698  esp bce01698  eip be7d4de5
[  +57 ms] backtrace:
[        ]       #00 pc 013cade5
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #01 pc 013e3673
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #02 pc 0146b58e
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #03 pc 0163ead3
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #04 pc 0163e9a5
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #05 pc 0163ee93
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #06 pc 0163ec7f
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #07 pc 011f43b5
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #08 pc 011f500a
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #09 pc 011f5e32
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #10 pc 011a2f9b
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #11 pc 011f48e4
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #12 pc 011f464c
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[        ]       #13 pc 0120276f
/data/app/com.example.great_places-8aRXGQi2nu_naeDUo8qoOQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.s
o (BuildId: 41b41257bd3fecb2110b68babe76fd09ee5a57bd)
[ +528 ms] Service protocol connection closed.
[   +1 ms] Lost connection to device.
[   +4 ms] executing: /Users/lordvidex/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
emulator-5554 forward --list
[  +19 ms] Exit code 0 from:
/Users/lordvidex/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 forward
--list
[        ] emulator-5554 tcp:58681 tcp:45635
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/lordvidex/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp:58681
[  +20 ms] DevFS: Deleting filesystem on the device
(file:///data/user/0/com.example.great_places/code_cache/greatplacesMECEQC/great
places/)
[ +258 ms] Ignored error while cleaning up DevFS: TimeoutException after
0:00:00.250000: Future not completed
[   +1 ms] executing: /Users/lordvidex/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
emulator-5554 forward --list
[  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from:
/Users/lordvidex/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 forward
--list
[   +2 ms] "flutter run" took 41,422ms.
[ +214 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 209ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 0
```

Now, I ran the exact same code on the iOS emulator and on a real Android device and there was no crash. What was the cause of this and how can I be sure it won't crash on real devices after publishing the app? 
Code to MapScreen can be viewed [here](https://pastiebin.com/5fb2da88628ac)

> flutter -version

```
Flutter 1.22.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1aafb3a8b9 (3 days ago) • 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
Engine • revision 2c956a31c0
Tools • Dart 2.10.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try it with a real device.

You can attach you real device to your computer and build on it with `flutter run -d {device Name/Id}`

The device name/id can be found with the command `flutter devices`

The emulators are not perfect, and some features can cause crash (for exemple accessing the gallery on an iOS device cause crash in Flutter).

Comment: It works on a real device. I tested it on my device and the iOS emulator but the android emulator crashes.. I can't seem to figure out why from the logs however